# Display month in Spanish

Tags: javascript, date

I have this code but it displays first 3 letters of month in english. How can I change it to spanish?

```
if (secondsPast > 86400) {
    var date = new Date(timestamp);
    var currentDate = new Date(now);
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.toDateString().match(/ [a-zA-Z]*/)[0].replace(' ', '');
    var year = date.getFullYear() == currentDate.getFullYear() ? '' : ', ' + date.getFullYear();

    return month + ' ' + day + ' ' + year;

}
```

Comment: Hi, it is a JS question.

Answer (score 26):

You can use `toLocaleDateString()`.

The toLocaleDateString() method returns a string with a language sensitive representation of the date portion of this date.

Please read more about it at [moz wiki](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Example:

```js
var event = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));
var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
    
console.log(event.toLocaleDateString('es-ES', options));
```

Comment: You can also use just [*toLocaleString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date.prototype.tolocalestring) with the same options. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

**In PHP:**
From the DateTime format page:

> This method does not use locales. All output is in English.

If you need locales look into [strftime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) Example:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");
$string = "24/11/2014";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $string);
echo strftime("%A",$date->getTimestamp());
```

Comment: @RobG Sorry for the wrong post, I have edited the answer now. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: You should provide an answer using a `javascript` valid syntax, make sure question it is written on that language.